# My version of angular CLI is greater that demanded but I get an error anyway

Tags: angular, heroku, angular-cli

I'm trying to push a small app I made in angular JS, but I get an error with heroku telling me that

Version of @angular/compiler-cli needs to be 2.3.1 or greater. Current version is "6.0.3".

Comment: @Sajeetharan I've already upvoted your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project needs a dev dependency for @angular/compiler-cli.

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/compiler-cli@<your angular version>
```

EDIT

```
npm install --save-dev @ngtools/webpack@latest
```

Comment: Hi @Sajeetharan, it didn't work, when I entered your command I received the warning "npm WARN The package @angular/cli is included as both a dev and production dependency.". Then when I tried to rehost it on heroic I still have the same error as in my question.

Comment: try with npm install --save-dev @ngtools/webpack@latest

Comment: Unfortunately no. However I did find my problem. The dev version of angular/cli was different than the prod version. The dev was 6.0.3 and the prod one was 1. something.  Weird bug